# SSRS - single Data Source connection to 2,000 databases

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

My project is for a retail giant who has over 2,000 stores. Data is collected in each store and maintained in its own local store database with a number of tables (the DB structure is identical for all stores, including table structure).

Therefore I need a different connection string for each store's database. I was wondering if I could create a report in SSRS by which I can select the stores and access the information.

Is there a way that I can map all 2,000 connections to a single Data Source ?

Comment: Does the company have a reporting strategy for this? I'll be surprised if a company with 2000 retail locations doesn't have a decent strategy for centralized reporting. There is likely already some regular job running for data extraction or replication that could assist you in avoiding this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create views to `UNION ALL` the data from all stores into a single object - one for each table you wish to access. These views could be created programmatically if the structure of each store's database is identical and could reside on a single instance of SQL Server which your report could then connect to through its Data Source.

As an example, let's pretend your databases have just two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    SaleID INT,
    CustomerID INT,
    Amount DECIMAL(19,4)
)

CREATE TABLE staff (
    StaffID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    YearsService INT
)
```

and let's assume you have only 3 stores, each with a SQL instance you can connect to from your central location (set up as Linked Servers) containing the database `CompanyData`:

```
SELECT * FROM Store1.CompanyData.dbo.sales
SELECT * FROM Store2.CompanyData.dbo.sales
SELECT * FROM Store3.CompanyData.dbo.sales
```

You could run a cursor like the following to generate `CREATE VIEW` scripts for the two tables in your databases:

```
DECLARE @SalesSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE VIEW dbo.GlobalSales AS '
DECLARE @StaffSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE VIEW dbo.GlobalStaff AS '
DECLARE @currentServer NVARCHAR(128)

DECLARE allServers CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name
    FROM SYS.SERVERS
    WHERE is_linked = 1

OPEN allServers
FETCH NEXT FROM allServers INTO @currentServer

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SalesSQL = @SalesSQL + ' SELECT ''' + @currentServer + ''' AS [Server], SaleId, CustomerID, Amount FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@currentServer) + '.CompanyData.dbo.Sales UNION ALL'
    SET @StaffSQL = @StaffSQL + ' SELECT ''' + @currentServer + ''' AS [Server], StaffId, Name, YearsService FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@currentServer) + '.CompanyData.dbo.Staff UNION ALL'
    FETCH NEXT FROM allServers INTO @currentServer
END

CLOSE allServers
DEALLOCATE allServers

SET @SalesSQL = LEFT(@SalesSQL,LEN(@SalesSQL)-6)
SET @StaffSQL = LEFT(@StaffSQL,LEN(@StaffSQL)-6)
EXEC sp_executesql @SalesSQL
EXEC sp_executesql @StaffSQL
```

This will then leave you with two views `GlobalSales` and `GlobalStaff` which sit on the same SQL Server and can be connected to with a single Data Source from an SSRS report.

If you have a very large number of tables in your databases, you could further automate the process by dynamically fetching the details of each relevant table in the databases, rather than specifying them explicitly as I have above.

Comment: `UNION ALL` will probably have much better performance in this case versus `UNION` but it's hard to imagine either as an acceptable answer for one report.

Comment: @JamieF fair point, but we'll never have any duplicate records to remove in my rather contrived example - will this definitely mean that `UNION ALL` will perform better than `UNION`? Out of interest why do you think this approach is unacceptable? I don't disagree that it's not particularly elegant and doesn't feel "neat", but it would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you don't have duplicates, `UNION ALL` will be much better. `UNION ALL` won't even look for duplicates, where `UNION` will look for duplicates 1999 times.
Will your approach work? Yeah, probably. But every query of this table will query 2000 databases. If these are on different servers, I wouldn't be surprised with awful performance.

Comment: @JamieF fair enough, I suppose some kind of data warehousing would be a better solution (if the DB infrastructure itself cannot be centralised) - even if it's something as primitive as a nightly data dump from each store to some central database which can then be queried by the OP as required?

Comment: Yes, indexes could then be created on the consolidated tables, and even if kept in a relational store, performance would be much better. OLAP or other reporting oriented storage would help even more. Reporting on data from 2000 locations is done all the time, but usually not by connecting to 2000 databases.

Comment: Thanks for accepting [Viji](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3990172/viji) - if you found this answer helpful, please feel free to upvote it as well, but I would recommend looking into data warehousing as discussed with [Jamie F](http://stackoverflow.com/users/400375/jamie-f) in the comments above - this is likely to be the better solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create 2000 different source connection within single one. You could specify each source connection separately.